# How to use copyObjectRequest() when source and destination have a space character in them?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, copy

I am trying to copy from AWS S3 using `CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest()` method with source and destination having a space character, but I get a copy object error.

Below is the code snippet.

```
sourceKey = "/Test Folder/test.png";
destinationKey = "Test Folder/test.png";
 final CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest =
                new CopyObjectRequest(
                        bucketName, sourceKey,
                        bucketName, destinationKey);
        copyObjectRequest.setCannedAccessControlList(CannedAccessControlList.PublicReadWrite);
```

I tried to replace `%20` (URL encoded) in source and destination with `+` and  (Space), but both didn't work.